How to avoid delay with node-oracledb getRows()?
We are trying to execute stored procedure from typescript. SP itself takes around 30 seconds and unfortunately we can't improve it. However, we found that below statement - const rows = await outbinds.c_tasksfilterresult?.getRows(); is taking 25 seconds to complete.
We tried to fetch with startIndex set to 0 and pageSize set to 10, 50 ,100. For 10 records it took 45 sec while for 50 & 100 records it took 25, 28 seconds respectively.
Can you please help us to understand why this is happening and how can we improve it.
Versions:
Node-OracleDB: 6.5.1
Node: 21.6.1

Output:
[22:56:14.893]: "Started extracting rows"
[22:56:38.613]: "Completed extracting rows"

Code:
export async function getTasksListFilterResult(context: UserContext, request: tasksfilterrequest): Promise < tasksfilterresponse | undefined > {
    let response: tasksfilterresponse | undefined;
    const sql: string = `BEGIN GET_TASKS_FILTER_RESULT(
            :p_assignedperson,
            :p_datecreatedmax,
            .,
            .,
            .,
            :p_startindex, 
            :p_pagesize, 
            :p_totalrecords, 
            :c_tasksfilterresult
        ); 
        END;`;
    const execOptions: OracleDB.ExecuteOptions = {
        outFormat: OracleDB.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT,
        prefetchRows: 500,
        fetchArraySize: 500,
    };
    //define stored procedure bind parameters
    .
    .
    .
    const p_totalrecords: OracleDB.BindParameter = {
        dir: OracleDB.BIND_OUT,
        type: OracleDB.NUMBER,
    };
    const c_tasksfilterresult: OracleDB.BindParameter = {
        dir: OracleDB.BIND_OUT,
        type: OracleDB.CURSOR,
    };
    //put all bind params in an object
    const bindParams = {
        p_assignedperson,
        p_datecreatedmax,
        .,
        .,
        .,
        p_startindex,
        p_pagesize,
        p_totalrecords,
        c_tasksfilterresult,
    };
    //execute sql stored procedure
    let dbConnection: OracleDB.Connection | undefined;
    try {
        dbConnection = await OracleDB.getConnection("tasks");
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(error, `Error while acquiring db connection`);
        throw error;
    }
    logger.info(`Executing Stored procedure`);
    if (dbConnection) {
        try {
            const result = await dbConnection.execute(sql, bindParams, execOptions);
            logger.info(`Executed Stored procedure`);
            const outbinds = await result?.outBinds;
            response = {
                records: [],
                totalrecords: 0,
            };
            logger.info(`Started extracting rows`);
            const rows = await outbinds.c_tasksfilterresult?.getRows();
            logger.info(`Completed extracting rows`);
            for (const row of rows) {
                logger.info(`Started iterating`);
                if (row && typeof row === "object") {
                    .,
                    .,
                    .,
                } else {
                    record = row as tasksrecord;
                }
                response.records?.push(record);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            logger.error(error, `Error while fetching tasks list filter results from db`);
            throw error;
        } finally {
            await dbConnection?.close();
        }
        logger.info(`Completed stored procedure data parsing`);
    }
}


Construct a simpler testcase and experiment with the tuning parameters, how you call getRows() etc.  If you still have issues, update your question with the simplified testcase - make sure it includes SQL to create the table & data.

Also, per documentation and examples, always close the resultset.
